# LDAP Search function very slow

Tags: php, ajax, ldap

I'm trying to use my ldap search, it's sort of working, however each search query takes like 10-20 seconds to give me back results. Although I have to work with like 50.000 entries (users) in my active directory and you would say no wonder it takes so much time, since ldap_search is O(N), I won't believe that it really needs so much time.

I have a textbox where I can type names. After the third typed letter the search function triggers and passes the textbox.value as parameter to the PHP file below (via AJAX).

```
<?php

error_reporting(E_ERROR | E_PARSE);

if(filter_input_array(INPUT_POST))
{
$term = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'term');
$username = 'username';
$password = "password";
$ldap_host = array('host1', 'host2', 'host3');
$ldap_base_dn = "baseDN";

foreach ($ldap_host as $host)
{
    $connect = ldap_connect($host);

    if($connect)
    {
        break;
    }

    if(!$connect && $host == end($ldap_host))
    {
        exit(">> Could not connect to any of the given LDAP servers. <<");
    }
}

ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_PROTOCOL_VERSION, 3);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_REFERRALS, 0);
ldap_set_option($connect, LDAP_OPT_SIZELIMIT, 20);

$bind = ldap_bind($connect, $username, $password);
$search_filter = '(&(objectClass=person)(cn=*'.$term.'*))';
$attributes = array();
$attributes[] = 'givenname';
$attributes[] = 'mail';
$attributes[] = 'samaccountname';
$attributes[] = 'sn';
$attributes[] = 'cn';
$result = ldap_search($connect, $ldap_base_dn, $search_filter, $attributes);
$ArrayOfHumanoids = array();

if (FALSE !== $result)
{
$entries = ldap_get_entries($connect, $result);

    for ($i = 0; $i < $entries['count']; $i++)
{
        if (!empty($entries[$i]['givenname'][0]) &&
        !empty($entries[$i]['mail'][0]) &&
        !empty($entries[$i]['samaccountname'][0]) &&
        !empty($entries[$i]['sn'][0]) &&
        'Shop' !== $entries[$i]['sn'][0] &&
        'Account' !== $entries[$i]['sn'][0])
        {
    $ad_users[strtoupper(trim($entries[$i]['samaccountname'][0]))] = array('email' => strtolower(trim

($entries[$i]['mail'][0])), 'first_name' => trim($entries[$i]['givenname'][0]), 'last_name' => trim($entries[$i]

['sn'][0]));

            array_push($ArrayOfHumanoids, $entries[$i]['cn'][0] . "+");
        }
}
}

if(count($ArrayOfHumanoids) == 0)
{
    echo "<div>Sorry, no match found!<br></div>";
}
else
{
    foreach($ArrayOfHumanoids as $userVar)
    {
        echo $userVar;
    }
}

ldap_unbind($connect);
}

?>
```

$term is the searching parameter that I pass at each keystroke. In the AJAX callback function, as you see I return with ArrayOfHumanoids, which json callback gets and splits by + string. I have no problem with that part. I just don't get it why it is so slow. I'm new to LDAP though, or recursion. Thank you in advance, I appreciate any kind of tips!

Comment: Is it the search or connection that takes a long time?

Comment: I'm wondering too. Search I guess, but I can't really seperate the 2 because if I want to search I have to connect first.

Comment: Don't use ajax, access the page directly, use echo's before and after the connection, see if that's the issue? Also set the ldap debug option to get more information: `ldap_set_option(NULL, LDAP_OPT_DEBUG_LEVEL, 7);`

Comment: How am I supposed to use it without AJAX? I mean, the textBox's value should be sent at each keystroke and I can only do that by using js onkey* event. And I can't call the SearchNames() function with that.

Comment: Open your network tab in your web inspector, find the ajax call, right click, choose "Open link in new window"

Comment: Ok, I deleted all the searching lines and just let the connection do the work, echoed before, after, as you told. It took like 5-6-7 seconds just to connect. :o

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I found out what caused the problem. I changed the hosts to IPs instead of the actual url, now its much more faster, really. Thanks **Ohgodwhy** for pointing out that the connection was the issue, not the searching.